# スマートフォンサイトであるページを開いた際に、所定箇所（アンカー）がページの最上段になる設定にしたいです。（ページ最上段にリダイレクトされることなく）

Tags: ios, android, html

どうかご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

スマートフォンサイトのページ作成で、以下の用に複数のブロックを使用しております。そこであるページからこのページ（以下のアドレス）を開いた際に、ブロックCの最上段がスマートフォン画面の最上段になるように設定したいです。

ブロックA
ブロックB
->ブロックC
ブロックD
ブロックE

そこで、送り元のページでの開きたいページのリンク（アンカー箇所）を以下の様に設定し、

xxx.com/user_data/site1.php#set

そのページにあるブロックCのhtmlの最上段に以下の設定を致しました。

cブロック内

試しましたところ、当該ページを開いた際に、一瞬Cブロックの最上段にジャンプするのですが、その直後にページの最上段（ブロックAの上）に通常通りにリダイレクトします。

デフォルトでページの最上段にリダイレクトするようになっているかのようなのですが(OSか何かの設定)、

どうすればアンカー箇所がページ最上段に設定されるようになるかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

Os：　Android 7.1.2
Os： iOS 11.0.3(15A432)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://m.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/q11183021671

Comment: サンプルコードか何かありませんか？また、アンカーでないとダメなのでしょうか？遷移させたくないのであればJavaScriptでもいいような気がします。アンカーの処理については端末のブラウザ依存ですので、端末依存といえば端末依存ですね。

Comment: Myaku様、ご返信頂きまして感謝いたします。サンプルコードは送り元の設定がxxx.com/user_data/site1.php#set、送り先がcブロック内に<a name="set"></a>という設定です。この様にページの所定の箇所がページ最上段に設定されるようにしたいケース（その後、ページトップに遷移しないようにする）では通常、皆様どの様に設定されているのでしょうか。また、JavaScriptを使用した場合、どのような設定にすべきか、簡単なコードをご紹介頂けませんでしょうか。